# What is a presentation of a manifestly positive definite metric on Euclidean AdS?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

One of the standard metrics in global coordinates that I found being used for Euclidean AdS is this,

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{z^2}(dt^2 - dz^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} dx_i^2)$$

- But this is not positive definite unless $p$ is even!
  So how is this a correct metric that physics papers in particular seem to be using for Euclidean AdS? (I understand that EAdS is defined to be a Riemannian manifold as opposed to just AdS)

  Is there an implicit interpretation of it which is different?
- Is there a presentation of global metric on Euclidean AdS which is manifestly positive definite?

---

Some references also use $ds^2 = \frac{1}{z^2}(dz^2 - dt^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} dx_i^2)$ which tries make the point that AdS is foliated by flat Minkowski spaces. But then its unclear to me why this metric is also claimed to be an ``Euclidean AdS" given that this is also not positive definite!

Any explanations clarifying this would also be helpful!

Comment: It's *never* positive definite. What are you thinking of with the parity of $p$? Are they referring to the restriction to some submanifold as being Riemannian (positive definite)?

Comment: Isn't Euclidean AdS a Riemannian manifold? If, yes, it should have a PD metric and possibly globally defined because it has a global chart. What is it explicitly?

Comment: I am not familiar with the physics lingo, but the metric you've written down is obviously a Lorentz metric (signature $(1,p)$). The other one is signature $(p,1)$. Neither is Riemannian.

Comment: Exactly what is getting me confused! My understanding has been that EAdS is defined as a Riemannian manifold! But do see what is said here at the bottom of page 5 and 6 (https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/fall08/handouts/lecture11.pdf) they are shifting to a coordinate system where the metric is PD - like in the ``Upper Half Plane" coordinates at the end of page 6. How is the signature changing by shifting coordinates!?

Comment: Problem starts with references like this : equation 2.15 here https://sites.krieger.jhu.edu/jared-kaplan/files/2016/05/AdSCFTCourseNotesCurrentPublic.pdf 

Here the author seems to be calling this an "Euclidean AdS" but his metric is not PD!

Comment: Yes, they are doing exactly what I suggested in my first remark. If you look at the hyperboloid in Lorentz space, the restriction of the Lorentzian metric *to it* is a Riemannian metric of constant negative curvature.

Comment: Thanks! So to confirm (a) the Upper Half Plane coordinates is a global coordinates on Euclidean AdS, right? It is not a local patch and (b) equation 2.15 in the lecture notes of Kaplan attached above are not Euclidean AdS (although somehow confusingly its a part of the Euclidean AdS chapter of his notes!).

Comment: Yes, again he's restricting to the hyperboloid. I'm not taking the time to study this carefully. But notice he keeps referring to Euclidean signature, so a lot of these coordinates are motivated by taking the usual PD signature case.